# Why do I get a 424 Object Required error when trying to set the range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, so apologies for any especially amateur mistakes.

I'm trying to run the match function on some user input from a form (the variable is named client below), and use the row from the match function to store user input related to that row.

I get a

> 424 Object Required

Error when I try to run the code. I've inserted a comment in the code below where I believe the mistake is.

```
Private Sub OK_Test_Click()    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim client As String

    client = LastNameSearch.Text

    Set rng = OutputSheet.Range("B2:B8") 'debugger brings me here, 
                                          tells me rng = Nothing

    rowLocation = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(client, rng, 0)

    Cells(C, rowLocation) = CaseStatusBox.Text
    Cells(D, rowLocation) = StaffEntryBox.Text
    Cells(G, rowLocation) = Date 
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `OutputSheet` actually set to anything?

Comment: OutputSheet is the name of the worksheet I want to search in and edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to apologize, this happens all the time! :)

`Option Explicit` isn't specified, and `OutputSheet` isn't defined.

That makes `OutputSheet` an undeclared `Variant/Empty` variable, off which you can't legally make a member call, since it's not an object - hence "object required".

With `Option Explicit` specified at the top of the module, the code wouldn't compile: the VBE would be warning you about `OutputSheet` being undeclared.

In order for `OutputSheet` to exist, you need to find that sheet in the *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R), then change its `(Name)` property (F4) to `OutputSheet`.

[image: properties toolwindow]

Or, you can declare an `OutputSheet As Worksheet` variable, and `Set` it to a valid `Worksheet` object reference - for example:

```
Dim OutputSheet As Worksheet
Set OutputSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OutputSheet")
```

That assumes the sheet exists in the `ActiveWorkbook` with a "tab name" of `OutputSheet`; note that the user can easily change this; the `(Name)` property is much harder to change for a user, but it requires the sheet to exist in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time.

---

Note that the unqualified `Cells` calls near the bottom of the procedure, are implicitly referring to whatever worksheet currently happens to be the `ActiveSheet` - consider qualifying them with a proper `Worksheet` object reference. If you mean to write to `OutputSheet`, that means:

```
OutputSheet.Cells(C, rowLocation) = CaseStatusBox.Text
OutputSheet.Cells(D, rowLocation) = StaffEntryBox.Text
OutputSheet.Cells(G, rowLocation) = Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Worksheets() function.

```
 Set rng = Worksheets("OutputSheet").Range("B2:B8")
 Debug.Print (rng.Count) 'Returns 7
```

I can't test your whole code though because I'm not sure what `LastNameSearch` refers to.